# Why does std::make_pair return a pair of reference types

Tags: c++, std-pair

I'm learning about pairs from the textbook by Koffman and Wolfgang. The sample implementation they gave of make_pair looks like this:

```
template<typename Type1, typename Type2>
  make_pair(const Type1& first_value, const Type2& second_value) {
    return pair<Type1&, Type2&>(first_value, second_value);
  }
```

I do not understand why they use Type1& and Type2& for instantiating the pair template in the return statement instead of just Type1 and Type2.

Comment: That can't work, there is no return type...

Comment: It's just an error in the book.

Comment: I just had a look at the beginning of that book and well...

Comment: -1: I fear the quote is not correct.

Comment: @DieterLücking -1: the quote is correct and anyone with Internet connection can check it.

Comment: @n.m. How can i check it (without illegal download) ?

Comment: amazon.com, find the book, look inside the book, search for the quote, find the quote, compare.

Comment: Understandably, the book did seem to miss the return type. But I am not asking about the syntax error. I am much more curious as to why they used pair<Type1&, Type2&> instead of pair<Type1, Type2>. Can anyone answer that?

Comment: @allenylzhou: it would be better if you could cross-check your textbook and provide the *exact* quote.

Comment: The quote is correct (can be verified on Amazon's look inside, just search for `make_pair`). This is just a typo in the book (though a rather egregious one at that).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know `make_pair` has the following prototype:

```
template<class Type1, class Type2>
std::pair<Type1,Type2> make_pair(Type1 first_value, Type2 second_value);
```

(Note: slightly different since C++11)

See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair.

This is also what the standard says in `§20.3.3 [pairs.spec]`. So this must be an error in the book (or you may have overlooked something).